# Configuring discovery events in gridgain

Tags: events, gridgain, ignite

I configured to listen to discovery events in gridgain using remoteListen method but when i call future.get() i get the following exception

here is the exception stack trace
lass org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to serialize object: StartRequestData [prjPred=null, clsName=null, depInfo=null, hnd=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridEventConsumeHandler@7f977fba, bufSize=1,
 interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

```
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller.marshal(GridOptimizedMarshaller.java:316)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1043)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.startRoutine(GridContinuousProcessor.java:501)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridEventsImpl.remoteListen(GridEventsImpl.java:101)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridEventsImpl.remoteListen(GridEventsImpl.java:88)
    at com.cmc.facts.startup.GridConfig.remoteListen(GridConfig.java:174)
    at com.cmc.facts.startup.GridConfig.afterPropertiesSet(GridConfig.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)Sep 28, 2015 2:10:43 PM org.gridgain.grid.logger.java.GridJavaLogger info
```

INFO:  Completed preloading in ASYNC mode [cache=PIDCache, time=250 ms]

```
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Must implement java.io.Serializable or set GridOptimizedMarshaller.setRequireSerializable() to false (note that performance may degrade if object is not Se
rializable): com.cmc.facts.startup.GridConfig
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.write(GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.java:816)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:197)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeFields(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:489)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:301)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.write(GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.java:820)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:197)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:128)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridEventConsumeHandler.writeExternal(GridEventConsumeHandler.java:301)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeExternalizable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:269)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.write(GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.java:810)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:197)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:128)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$StartRequestData.writeExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1371)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeExternalizable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:269)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.write(GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.java:810)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:197)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:128)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller.marshal(GridOptimizedMarshaller.java:311)
        ... 44 more

Comment: I laso tried setting the serialized = false for Gridmarshaller in grid configuration, but then I get a externelizable exception

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you declared your listener as an anonymous class. Anonymous classes in Java have a link to the parent class, so the instance of this parent class is also serialized. If this is the case, I would recommend to convert the listener to inner static class and mark it with Serializable interface. This way you will have more control on what is serialized in your application.